# Iterate using keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a string (`string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'`), and I want to add it to an empty list, always a condition is satisfied. A certain letter should not be in a determined position of the string, but it is on the other positions. For instance, the letter `A` should not be in the position `5` but should be in any other position. If this condition is satisfied, I append the string to the list; if not, I don't append it.

```
string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'
if 'A' != string[5] and ('A' in string[0:5] or 'A' in string[6:len(string)]):
        word_list.append(string)
```

On the other hand, I want to check if the letter `Z` is not in position `6` that is `True`, but I would add only if `Z` is in any other position that is not position  `6`. In this case, `Z` is not in the string, so I would not add it to the list.

I want to do this iteratively, defining a dictionary (`letter:position`) and checking all the letters and positions added to the dictionary. For instance, the whole code to do this **manually** would be something like this:

```py
string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'

word_list=[]

letter_change_pos = {'A':5,'T':3,'Z':6}

if 'A' != string[5] and ('A' in string[0:5] or 'A' in string[6:len(string)]):
    word_list.append(string)
if 'T' != string[3] and ('T' in string[0:3] or 'T' in string[4:len(string)]):
    word_list.append(string)
if 'Z' != string[6] and ('Z' in string[0:6] or 'Z' in string[7:len(string)]):
    word_list.append(string)
    
print(word_list)
```

How could I do this using a **for loop**?

Comment: I would suggest ```regex``` for this so that they can easily do your job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question requires that (1) loop on each character of the dictionary, (2) check if the character is in the string and not in the specified index, (3) if yes, append the string in the list, and (4) otherwise, don't append the string.

A quick solution using loops can be:

```
# The required string to check.
string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'
# Create an empty list.
wordList = []
# The dictionary rules for the string.
letterChangePos = {'A': 5, 'T': 3, 'Z': 6}

# Loop on each character of the dictionary.
for key in letterChangePos.keys():
  # Check if the character is in the string.
  if (key in string):
    # Check if the key is not the same as the character in the specified index.
    if (key != string[letterChangePos[key]]):
      wordList.append(string)

# Print the list.
print(wordList)
```

Using the comprehensive lists approach, the solution would be:

```
# The required string to check.
string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'
# The dictionary rules for the string.
letterChangePos = {'A': 5, 'T': 3, 'Z': 6}

wordList = [
  string for key in letterChangePos.keys()
  if ((key in string) and (key != string[letterChangePos[key]]))
]

# Print the list.
print(wordList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_list(test_string, position_dict):
    word_list = []
    for key, value in position_dict.items():
        if key != test_string[value - 1] and (key in string[0:value-1] or key in string[value:]):
            word_list.append(test_string)
    return word_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'

    letter_change_pos = {'A': 5, 'T': 3, 'Z': 6}

    print(check_list(string, letter_change_pos))
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what the title "Iterate using keys and values of a dictionary" has to do with your question.

You could write a function that checks every character in a string like this:

```py
def check_invalid_character_positions(string, invalid_positions):
    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        if invalid_positions.get(char) == idx:
            return False

    # Now check that the characters in invalid_positions are present
    # elsewhere in the string
    return not set(invalid_positions).difference(string)
```

Use it like:

```py
>>> string = 'OBEQAMXITWA'
>>> invalid_positions = {'A': 5, 'T': 3, 'Z': 6}
>>> if check_invalid_character_positions(string, invalid_positions):
...     word_list.append(string)
```

Per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487884/iterate-using-keys-and-values-of-a-dictionary#comment128051392_72487884) you could also technically do this with a regexp I think, but that would be more complicated.

Comment: While the answer has its own internal logic, it doesn't work as written (`word_list` is undefined and uninitialized) and even if that is overlooked, it doesn't do what the question asks. The question clearly indicates that `word_list` should have `string` appended twice for the sample input used by both the question and this answer: once for 'A' and a second time for 'T' (and not for 'Z' since it's not in `string`). Another answer (the one accepted by OP) does exactly this. This answer, however, never reaches its `append()` line for the sample input.

Comment: Had not been familiar with that term before your post, but looked it up and don't think it applies. My comment simply concurs with that of OP: upon running the code in your answer, I found that it didn't work and that when I made the fixes necessary to run it, it didn't give the results specified in the question (or in the accepted answer). You may want to consider updating your answer to make it work (as your previous comment claims it does) or at least clarifying why it doesn't do what the question asks. Otherwise, emphatic statements like "It absolutely does work" are subject to comment.